# How to find indices of matching elements in arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, comparison, indices

I have two vectors, vector A is (1298,1), Vector B varies in a for loop but is always just a column vector, I am trying to use numpy.where to find the A-indices of the elements in B. Currently I have a for loop combing through Vector B element-wise and using numpy.isclose but I was wondering if anyone knows a quicker function and/or how to do this without a nested for loop? It works but very slowly.
The for loops looks like this

````
sphere_indices=[]
for k in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
         if np.isclose(B[j,0],A[k,0]):
              sphere_indices.append(k) ```
````

Comment: Can you give some input examples?

Comment: Can you also use `A` and `B` in your code so we know which is which?

Comment: So A is the (1298,1) vector and B is typically a size between (10,1) and (1,1), the elements are all integers ranging from 1 to 10,000 that correspond to atom-id #s used by the simulation software (this is a post-processing script for MD simulations)

Answer (score 0):

There was never any reason to iterate through the all 1298 elements of vector A, in order to use numpy.where and numpy.isclose I just needed to use the elements in B one at a time so numpy can broadcast properly. The following code runs much faster. Any further improvements are always welcome.

````
                    for j in range(len(index)):
                        sphere_indices1=np.where(np.isclose(sphere_index[:,0],index[j,0]))
                        sphere_indices.append(sphere_indices1[0])```
````